# How should we deal with Coursera homework related questions?

Tags: discussion, ethics, homework

After the post about removing the homework tag I have a kind of related question.

I am active in the Scala category and its creator, Martin Odersky is giving a class on Coursera with something like 30'000 students. Obviously some questions end up on stackoverflow. Thus I would like to know what is the correct attitude regarding those questions.

For now I see two categories:

- people who just copy paste the question
- people who worked on the assignment but still have a real question, which is as valuable as a usual question in stackoverflow.

For now, those Coursera-related questions have negative scores when they look like they are from Coursera even if their content is good.

PS:Coursera's policy is to forbid putting solutions online.

Comment: If it's givemethecodez kind of question, then close it. If the OP is having some problems, probably can answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As with vendor NDA's, homework, competitions etc...Stack Overflow users and moderators (and by extension, Stack Exchange network users and mods) are not here to police other SE user activities with regards to their agreements and contractual obligations to these organisations.

If a question falls within the guidelines of Stack Overflow's FAQ or indeed any other SE network site's FAQ then it's fair game. If Coursera or any other vendor/academic has a problem with content posted on our sites then they need to contact SE Inc. directly.